# Extract Fields from SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php, arrays, object, simplexml

If I have the following code which pulls xml feeds from a database, then converts them to SimpleXMLElement Arrays:

```
try{
    function processLink( $link , $appendArr ){
    ## gets url from database as outlined above.
        $xmlUrl = $link;
        #Loads the url above into XML    
        $ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);
        # -> Setup XML
        $appendArr[] = $ConvertToXml->channel->item;
    }
    #Connect to DB
    require_once '../../src/conn/dbc.php';
    $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=mydb',$db_user,$db_pass,array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
    $q = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT FW_ArtSrcLink FROM FW_ArtSrc WHERE OneSet=:OneSet and leagID = :TheLeagueID");
    $q->execute(array(':OneSet' => 1, ':TheLeagueID' => 14));    # SET LEAGUE HERE.
    $result = $q->fetchAll();
    $newsStory = array();

    foreach ($result as $value ){
            if ( is_array($value) ){
                foreach ( $value as $secondValue ){
                    processLink($secondValue , &$newsStory);
                }

                continue;
        }

        processLink($value , $newsStory);

    }    
    ## Don't want to do this, I want to output just the [title] and [link]         
    //print_r($newsStory);

}
```

If I just want to extract from the SimpleXMLElement Array the keys: [title] and [link] how do I do this with my current code?

I've tried using:

```
echo 'title'.$newStory->channel->item->title;
echo 'title'.$newStory->title;
echo 'title'.$value->title;
```

Output from print_r():

[image: img2]

All with with blank values, or nothing being echoed at all. How do I output both the **title** and **link**?

MODIFIED:

```
foreach ($newsStory as $story ) {
        echo "<hr>"."<a href='".$story->link."'>".$story->title."</a>"."<hr>";
    } 

The problem is... it prints some duplicates... how do I get ONLY unique links to display?
```

[image: img44]

**UPDATED FOREACH:**

```
$stories = array(); // contains all of the stories already output
    foreach ( $newsStory as $story ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $stories, $story->title ) ) {
            $stories[] = $story->title;
            echo "<hr>"."<a href='".$story->link."'>".$story->title."</a>"."<hr>";     
        } //if
    } //foreach
```

This outputs the warning( while still displaying duplicates):

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given on line 39:
```

It basically doesn't like this:

```
  if ( ! in_array( $stories, $story->title ) ) {
```

Comment: What is the output from `print_r()`?

Comment: Please see above update.

Comment: Run `print_r()` on `$ConvertToXml` and post the result. I suspect that is where your problem lies.

Comment: Joseph - please see 'MODIFIED' above. I've used your code, but it is listing duplicates of the echo output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the resulting array to output each item, like so:

```
<?php
$stories = array(); // contains all of the stories already output
foreach ( $newsStory as $story ) {
    if ( ! in_array( (string) $story->title, $stories ) ) {
        $stories[] = (string) $story->title;
        echo 'title'.$story->title;
    }
}
```

Update: Added code to check if story was already output.

Comment: Joseph, thanks for this. I'm getting a warning as shown in 'UPDATED FOREACH' above. Can you please check this out? I tried making the second parameter $stories, but that didnt seem to help..

Comment: Sorry about that. I have trouble remembering which functions take `needle, haystack` and which are `haystack, needle`. A very annoying inconsistency if you ask me. `$stories` should be second and you have to cast to a string (forgot about that).

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much Joseph! A+ for that help buddy!